# Thingspeak API Limit GET Requests?

Tags: rest-api

Is there a GET request rate limit for the Thingspeak API? So far I've only been able to find information about POST requests.

I have a data acquisition R script that I would like to run in parallel. I'm pausing ~1-second between each request currently, but when parallelized, I would be making 8 requests every 1-second instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A roundabout answer.

As per info at bottom of this answer, you get charged by a number of messages written, not by number of times someone reads the data.

That means you can experiment with multiple GET requests without having to worry about a cost, so run your script and see what happens.

NOTE: make sure that your script does not write any messages

Here is an excerpt from  https://thingspeak.com/pages/license_faq

> **4. What is a message?**
>
> ThingSpeak stores messages in channels. A message is defined as a write of up to 8 fields of data to a
> ThingSpeak channel. For example, a channel representing a weather
> station could include the following 8 fields of data: temperature,
> humidity, barometric pressure, wind speed, wind direction, rainfall,
> battery level, and light level. Each message cannot exceed 3000 bytes.
> Examples of messages include:
>
> 1. A write to a ThingSpeak channel using the REST API or target-specific ThingSpeak libraries
>    a. From an embedded device
>    b. From another computer
> 2. A write to a ThingSpeak channel using MQTT
> 3. A write to a ThingSpeak channel from MATLAB using thingspeakwrite or the REST API
> 4. A write to a ThingSpeak channel inside ThingSpeak using the MATLAB Analysis or MATLAB Visualizations Apps
> 5. Any writes to ThingSpeak triggered by a React or a Timecontrol

and

> **19. Does using any of the apps in ThingSpeak™ affect my messages in any way?**
>
> Your messages are consumed when you write data to a ThingSpeak
> channel. If you write data to a channel from one of the ThingSpeak
> Apps, you will consume messages. For example, if are using the MATLAB
> Analysis app to compute a value that is derived from data you have
> stored in ThingSpeak channels, you will not consume messages, but if
> you save/write that value to another channel, you will consume
> messages.